# Como usar o addHTML do jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Estou a algum tempo tentando utilizar o jsPDF para criar um pdf de uma página específica em um projeto. Porém, todos os exemplos que olhei que incluem esta função (addHTML) não funcionam. Nos exemplos do desenvolvedor (http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html) não existe nada referente ao addHTML sobrando somente o fromHTML que não satisfazem minhas necessidades devido ao fato de não renderizar o CSS.

Gostaria que se possivel alguém me explicasse como devo usar o addHTML para renderizar todo o  de uma página, incluindo o que devo incluir no meu  e no botão que irá chamar a função addHTML para que funcione corretamente.

Agradeço enormemente a ajuda.

Comment: Boa tarde, a resposta resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: sim, resolveu perfeitamente o problema. Obrigado.

Comment: Então marque a resposta como correta por favor, se tiver alguma duvida sobre isso pode ler as instruções aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Answer (score 4):

### jsPDF

`addHTML` é um método "super novo" e provavelmente não suporta todas propriedades CSS e HTML, portanto este deve ser o motivo de alguns do problemas que você enfrenta.

Um exemplo simples conforme a documentação:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
    var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    iframe.src = string;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

**Note:** que `jsPDF.fromHTML` também está em estágios iniciais (conforme o exemplo informa) e provavelmente não renderiza completamente, ou seja ainda não suporta várias propriedades CSS e HTML.

Note que a renderização não é "real", o que eu quero dizer o software apenas *simula* as propriedades CSS e HTML, ou seja ele tenta compensar vários aspectos do Motor de renderização do navegador, mas não suporta todas propriedades.

### html2canvas

Há um outro projeto que também é usado para tirar "fotos" da página, porém não é em formato PDF, o [`html2canvas`](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas), porém é totalmente experimental e também ainda tem muitas coisas a serem implementadas, mas demonstra estar bem avançado:

Exemplo de uso:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Se você usa resources de sites externos ou que estão em outras portas, como `https` carregando `http` ou ao contrário, portanto será necessário usar um `proxy`:

- [python - Google Appengine](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy)
- [node.js](https://github.com/BugHerd/html2canvas-proxy-node)
- [php](https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy)
- [asp.net (c#)](https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-csharp-proxy)
- [asp classic (vbscript)](https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-asp-vbscript-proxy)
- [python - qualquer framework](https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-python-proxy)

### Desenhando DOM com SVG dentro do Canvas

É possivel desenhar os *SVGs* dentro do *Canvas*, porém ao momento que usamos `<foreignObject>`, os navegadores `WebKit` e `Blink/Chromium` tem bloqueios de segurança quanto o uso disto, ou seja você pode desenhar, mas não pode usar `toDataURI` (no Firefox funciona se você usar [*CORS*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

O exemplo a seguir é simples, adquirido no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), para usar `<link>` (folhas de estilo) e propriedades CSS será necessário converte-las em `<style>` e converter os `url(...)` para o `Data URI Scheme` e mesmo assim fontes de texto não serão suportados (por incrível que pareça eu estou trabalhando a alguns meses em uma biblioteca que faz tudo isto, tira "foto" da página usando SVG, só parei por causa da questão das web-fontes, que é bem difícil de embutir no SVG), portanto você pode tentar, mas funcionará somente em navegadores com o motor Gecko (usado Firefox) e ainda será um pouco trabalhoso de importar, mas efeitos CSS e HTML todos funcionarão provavelmente, segue exemplo simples:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
           '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
           '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
             '<em>I</em> like' + 
             '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">' +
             'cheese</span>' +
           '</div>' +
           '</foreignObject>' +
           '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

Note que para usar o SVG é necessário um HTML (ou melhor XHTML) válido, para isto use este script:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");

//Adicione o seu html, como por exemplo document.documentElement.innerHTML
doc.write(STRING DO CONTEUDO HTML);

doc.documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns", doc.documentElement.namespaceURI);

var html = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc);

var docWidth  = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                         document.body.scrollWidth,
                         document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
                         document.body.offsetWidth,
                         document.documentElement.offsetWidth);

var docHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                         document.body.scrollHeight,
                         document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                         document.body.offsetHeight,
                         document.documentElement.offsetHeight);

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ' +
           'width="' + docWidth + '" height="' + docHeight + '">' +
           '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
             html +
           '</foreignObject>' +
           '</svg>';
```

### Conclusão

Com exceção do *SVG* + *Canvas*, nenhuma biblioteca tem suporte suficiente *ainda* para simular os efeitos HTML e CSS dos navegadores ainda e mesmo que consiga isto, ainda será sujeita a BUGs ou não conseguirá acompanhar os motores dos web-browsers em tempo real, pois é tudo "simulado".