# Passar API Google Maps para imagem JPG

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Tenho esse código abaixo:

```
   <iframe width='500' scrolling='no' height='200' frameborder='0' id='map' 
   marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=São Paulo 
   - SP, Brasil&daddr=Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil&output=embed'></iframe>
```

Que me retorna esse mapa:

[image: Mapa com Rota Traçada]

O que eu queria é saber como transformar esse mapa em uma imagem `jpg` dentro do php mantendo a rota desenhada.

Por que de tudo isso?

Estou gerando um arquivo **PDF** pelo **MPDF** mas a única coisa que ela não suporta é essa tag do `<iframe>` para o *Google Maps* e preciso desse mapa dentro do **PDF**.

Comment: Acredito que não exista nada para PHP que suporte isto. Wkhtmltopdf acredito ser a única opção. O bom é que é extremamente rápido, embora enorme (+40MB), e utiliza uma engine real para renderizar a página. Ela não é 100% estável no que se trata a `iframe`, no entanto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Google tem uma [API de mapas estáticos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps) que são servidos como imagem. É bem fácil de usar, basta construir a URL certa e colocar como `src` de uma imagem:

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=São Paulo, SP, Brazil&zoom=12&size=400x400">
```

O problema é que não existem parâmetros para traçar uma rota. Para isso, você precisa usar o serviço de rotas da [API do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), para obter os dados de uma linha (*polyline*), essa sim aceita pela API estática. Aí o código fica um pouco mais complexo, mas produz o resultado desejado:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {
    var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directions.route({
        origin: "São Paulo SP Brazil",
        destination: "Rio de Janeiro RJ Brazil",
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, rotaDisponivel);
}

function rotaDisponivel(dados, status) {
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Guaratinguetá%20SP%20Brasil&zoom=8&size=800x300&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|enc:"
    if(dados.routes[0]) {
        var div = document.getElementById('mapa');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = url + dados.routes[0].overview_polyline;
        div.appendChild(img);
    } else {
        // erro ao obter rota
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<p>O mapa vai carregar abaixo, pode demorar um pouco</p>
<div id="mapa"></div>
```

Comment: +1 Mapas estáticos, OMG tão simples! Nunca utilizei, mas isso é passado agora ;)

Answer (score 2):

Como já citado, [`html2canvas`](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) é uma ótima biblioteca para o uso, antes de começarmos tenha em mente:

- `html2canvas` não trabalha elementos DOM reais ele apenas simula eles com Canvas
- Ele é considerado alpha ou experimental, portanto ainda tem muito a evoluir (se bem que na maioria dos testes ele se saiu muito bem)
- Para acessar imagens de diferentes domínios será necessário o uso de proxy (feito por linguagens como php, python, java, etc).
- Acredito que o uso de `<iframe>` ainda não seja suportado, portanto o melhor neste caso é usar a API do google-maps ao invés de *iframes*.

### Usando a API do Google Maps

Um exemplo do uso do Google Maps seria:

```js
var parametreCarteVillage = {
    zoom                        : 9,
    center                      : new google.maps.LatLng(38.959409, -87.289124),
    disableDoubleClickZoom      : false,
    draggable                   : true,
    scrollwheel                 : true,
    panControl                  : false,
    disableDefaultUI            : true,
    mapTypeControl              : true,
    keyboardShortcuts           : true,
    mapTypeId                   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
  
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), parametreCarteVillage);
  
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:new google.maps.LatLng(38.959409,-87.289124),
  map: map,
  title: 'Titulo!'
});
```

```css
#map_canvas{
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Para adicionar mais opções ao mapa leia a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=pt-br)

### Usando o html2canvas

Recomendo baixar a versão *0.5.0-alpha* em https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases
e incluir na página que vai usar o Google Maps, deve ficar algo como:

```
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>

html2canvas(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    "logging": true //Habilita os logs
}).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        img.onload = null;
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});
```

Porém como mencionei anteriormente, para acessar imagens de diferentes domínios, no caso o seu domínio acessa as imagens do google, será necessário usar [`CORS`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), porém as imagens estão no domínio do Google e isto não temos controle, então teremos que usar proxy.

Proxy neste caso não é a tecnologia para usar um ip diferente na sua máquina, mas sim um script que roda no servidor e exibe a imagem do domínio externo como se estive-se no seu domínio, ou mesmo que sejam três domínios `seu-site.com`, `maps.google.com` e `proxy.seu-site.com` ele faz o uso de [`CORS`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) ou do [`data URI scheme`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

### Proxy para html2canvas

Eu desenvolvi quatro proxys em linguagens diferentes:

- **Proxy em PHP**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy
- **Proxy em C#**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-csharp-proxy
- **Proxy em Python**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-python-proxy (suporta qualquer framework)
- **Proxy em VbScript (para asp clássico)**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-asp-vbscript-proxy

O uso seria algo como (exemplo com `aspx`):

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    "logging": true, //Habilita os logs
    "proxy":"html2canvasproxy.ashx"
}).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        img.onload = null;
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});
```

Lista de opções estras para usar em `html2canvas(..., {opções}).then(...)`

| Opção | Tipo | padrão | Descrição |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `allowTaint` | `boolean` | `false` | Permite causar o taint quando houver imagens cross-origin |
| `background` | `string` | `#fff` | Troca a cor de fundo do canvas, se não espeficicado no dom use `undefined` para transparente |
| `height` | `number` | `null` | Limita a altura do em pixels. Se `null` irá renderezar com a altura total da janela |
| `letterRendering` | `boolean` | `false` | Usado para renderizar cada letra separadamente. É necessário se estiver usando `letter-spacing` |
| `logging` | `boolean` | `false` | Quando `true` mostra log no console do navegador |
| `proxy` | `string` | `undefined` | A url do proxy é usa da para carregar imagens cross-origin. Se não definido ou vazio as imagens não serão carregadas |
| `taintTest` | `boolean` | `true` | Testa cada imagem para antes de desenhar, para verificar se irá manchar o `<canvas>` |
| `timeout` | `number` | `0` | Tempo de espera para o carregamento das imagens em milesegundos. Se 0 não haverá esperar |
| `width` | `number` | `null` | Limita a largura do em pixels. Se `null` irá renderezar com a largura total da janela |
| `useCORS` | `boolean` | `false` | Se `true` tenta carregar as imagens com cross-origem, se não tenta usar o proxy |

**Relatado:** [Como usar o addHTML do jsPDF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55522/3635)

Answer (score 0):

Olá.
Amigo, para realizar este feito, eu faço a seguinte sugestão: Utilize a API do Google Maps e crie este mapa em uma DIV. Somente assim, você terá acesso ao evento tilesLoaded, que simboliza o total carregamento do mapa, possibilitando a você gerar um CANVAS e "imprimir" a imagem como PNG ou JPEG, possibilitando a passagem para o seu PHP. No IFRAME , as politicas de segurança do GOOGLE te impedem de acessar o conteúdo do mesmo, impossibilitando assim a manipulação do objeto, levando a soluções utilizando TIMEOUT que, em geral, são falhas.

Para a conversão do mapa para PNG ou JPEG, após a renderização tu pode usar :

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Ou após renderizar o mapa, utilizar o seu próprio meio de geração de PDF, que eu assumo ter origem do HTML.(Que supondo pelo motivo acima, pode não estar sendo exibido).
Espero ter ajudado. 
Boa sorte.