# Como tirar print (screenshot) de uma página web?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Gostaria de saber como tirar print de uma página, e salvar em imagem.

Segue exemplo para entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Havia me esquecido de adicionar a parte de salvar, acredito que tua necessidade seja salvar no servidor. Se não me avise.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se puder colocar também essa parte, ficarei agradecido ;)

Comment: Salvar no servidor? Ou salvar no desktop?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode deixar, vi que você colocou como salvar canvas no servidor.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Desenhando DOM com SVG dentro do Canvas

É possível desenhar os *SVGs* dentro do *Canvas*, porém ao momento que usamos `<foreignObject>`, os navegadores `WebKit` e `Blink/Chromium` tem bloqueios de segurança quanto o uso disto, ou seja você pode desenhar, mas não pode usar `toDataURI` (no Firefox funciona se você usar [*CORS*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

O exemplo a seguir é simples, adquirido no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), para usar `<link>` (folhas de estilo) e propriedades CSS será necessário converte-las em `<style>` e converter os `url(...)` para o `Data URI Scheme` e mesmo assim fontes de texto não serão suportados (por incrível que pareça eu estou trabalhando a alguns meses em uma biblioteca que faz tudo isto, tira "foto" da página usando SVG, só parei por causa da questão das web-fontes, que é bem difícil de embutir no SVG), portanto você pode tentar, mas funcionará somente em navegadores com o motor Gecko (usado Firefox) e ainda será um pouco trabalhoso de importar, mas efeitos CSS e HTML todos funcionarão provavelmente, segue exemplo simples:

```
var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

if (!('createObjectURL' in DOMURL)) throw new Error('Sem suporte a createObjectURL');

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
           '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
           '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
             '<em>I</em> like' + 
             '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">' +
             'cheese</span>' +
           '</div>' +
           '</foreignObject>' +
           '</svg>';

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

Para exportar a imagem você pode usar:

- [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
- [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

Note que para usar o SVG é necessário um HTML (ou melhor XHTML) válido, para isto use este script:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");

//Adicione o seu html, como por exemplo document.documentElement.innerHTML
doc.write(STRING DO CONTEUDO HTML);

doc.documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns", doc.documentElement.namespaceURI);

var html = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc);

var docWidth  = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                         document.body.scrollWidth,
                         document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
                         document.body.offsetWidth,
                         document.documentElement.offsetWidth);

var docHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight,
                         document.body.scrollHeight,
                         document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                         document.body.offsetHeight,
                         document.documentElement.offsetHeight);

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ' +
           'width="' + docWidth + '" height="' + docHeight + '">' +
           '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
             html +
           '</foreignObject>' +
           '</svg>';
```

### Usando o html2canvas

> Você pode usar o html2canvas, note que ele não tira uma foto real, mas
> sim tenta redesenhar os elementos da página, note que as demais
> respostas estão corretas, mas os exemplos provavelmente não
> funcionarão na versão atual do html2canvas, pois várias funções foram
> modificadas e passou a usa o `es6-promise`

Recomendo baixar a versão *0.5.0-alpha2* em https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases
e incluir na página que vai precisar tirar a "foto", deve ficar algo como:

```
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>

html2canvas(document.getElementById("id-do-meu-elemento"), {
    "logging": true //Habilita os logs
}).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        img.onload = null;
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});
```

Porém pode haver casos que a imagens sejam de diferentes domínios, será necessário usar [`CORS`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), então teremos que usar proxy.

Proxy neste caso não é a tecnologia para usar um ip diferente na sua máquina, mas sim um script que roda no servidor e exibe a imagem do domínio externo como se estive-se no seu domínio, ou mesmo que sejam três domínios `seu-site.com`, `maps.google.com` e `proxy.seu-site.com` ele faz o uso de [`CORS`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) ou do [`data URI scheme`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

### Proxy para html2canvas

Eu desenvolvi quatro proxys em linguagens diferentes:

- **Proxy em PHP**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy
- **Proxy em C#**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-csharp-proxy
- **Proxy em Python**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-python-proxy (suporta qualquer framework)
- **Proxy em VbScript (para asp clássico)**: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-asp-vbscript-proxy

O uso seria algo como (exemplo com `aspx`):

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("ID-DO-ELEMENTO"), {
    "logging": true, //Habilita os logs
    "proxy":"html2canvasproxy.ashx"
}).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        img.onload = null;
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});
```

Lista de opções estras para usar em `html2canvas(..., {opções}).then(...)`

| Opção | Tipo | padrão | Descrição |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `allowTaint` | `boolean` | `false` | Permite causar o taint quando houver imagens cross-origin |
| `background` | `string` | `#fff` | Troca a cor de fundo do canvas, se não espeficicado no dom use `undefined` para transparente |
| `height` | `number` | `null` | Limita a altura do em pixels. Se `null` irá renderezar com a altura total da janela |
| `letterRendering` | `boolean` | `false` | Usado para renderizar cada letra separadamente. É necessário se estiver usando `letter-spacing` |
| `logging` | `boolean` | `false` | Quando `true` mostra log no console do navegador |
| `proxy` | `string` | `undefined` | A url do proxy é usa da para carregar imagens cross-origin. Se não definido ou vazio as imagens não serão carregadas |
| `taintTest` | `boolean` | `true` | Testa cada imagem para antes de desenhar, para verificar se irá manchar o `<canvas>` |
| `timeout` | `number` | `0` | Tempo de espera para o carregamento das imagens em milesegundos. Se 0 não haverá esperar |
| `width` | `number` | `null` | Limita a largura do em pixels. Se `null` irá renderezar com a largura total da janela |
| `useCORS` | `boolean` | `false` | Se `true` tenta carregar as imagens com cross-origem, se não tenta usar o proxy |

### Conclusão sobre tirar foto da página

Com exceção do *SVG* + *Canvas*, nenhuma biblioteca tem suporte suficiente *ainda* para simular os efeitos HTML e CSS dos navegadores ainda e mesmo que consiga isto, ainda será sujeita a BUGs ou não conseguirá acompanhar os motores dos web-browsers em tempo real, pois é tudo "simulado".

- **Relatado:** [Como usar o addHTML do jsPDF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55522/3635)

---

### Salvando canvas no servidor

Conforme está minha resposta no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63018/3635 para fazer o upload de um imagem em canvas, faça o seguinte processo:

```
function uploadAjax(data, fileName, success, error)
{
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    oReq.open("POST", "upload.php?filename=" + fileName, true);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                success(oReq.responseText);
            } else {
                error(oReq.status);
            }
        }
    };
    oReq.send(data);
}

html2canvas(document.getElementById("id-do-meu-elemento"), {
    "logging": true //Habilita os logs
}).then(function(canvas) {
    uploadAjax(
        canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace(/^data[:]image\/(.*);base64,/, ""),
        "photo.jpg", function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
});
```

> Troque `image/jpeg` pelo formato que desejar, por exemplo `image/gif` ou `image/png`, assim por exemplo:
>
> ```
> canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
> ```

PHP para upload:

```
<?php
define('PASTA_UPLOAD', '/home/user/projeto/data');

if (isset($_GET['filename']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $cl = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];

    $tmpFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '~upload-');

    $file = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');
    $fh   = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    if ($file && $fh) {
        $data = '';
        while (FALSE === feof($fh)) {
            $data .= fgets($fh, 256);
        }
        fwrite($file, base64_decode($data));
    }

    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($fh) {
        fclose($fh);
    }

    echo 'OK';
    copy($tmpFile, PASTA_UPLOAD . '/' . $_GET['filename']);
} else {
    echo 'Requisição inválida';
}
```

### Salvando na maquina do usuário Desktop

Para salvar no Desktop, o navegador do usuário terá que ter suporte para o atributo `download` na tag `<a>` (todos navegadores modernos Desktop possuem), exemplo:

```
function canvasDownload(canvas, filename, formato) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/" + (formato ? formato : "jpeg") );
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
}
```

Note que é necessário adicionar o evento `downloadHtml2canvas` em uma ação do usário, como `click`, `mouseover`, etc, pois se não o script é bloqueado. Exemplo de uso:

```
<button id="gerar">Gerar</button>
<button id="salvar" disabled>Salvar</button>

<script>
(function() {
    var gerar  = document.getElementById("gerar"),
        salvar = document.getElementById("salvar"),
        currentCanvas = null;

    gerar.onclick = function() {
        salvar.disabled = true;
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("id-do-meu-elemento"), {
            "logging": true //Habilita os logs
        }).then(function(canvas) {
            currentCanvas = canvas;
            salvar.disabled = false;
        });
    };

    salvar.onclick = function() {
         if (currentCanvas !== null && salvar.disabled === false) {
             canvasDownload(currentCanvas, "foto.jpg");
         }
    };
})();
</script>
```

> **Nota:** se quiser salvar em outro formato basta ajustar assim:
>
> - `canvasDownload(currentCanvas, "foto.png", "png")`
> - `canvasDownload(currentCanvas, "foto.gif", "gif")`

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento poderia me falar se sua solução faz o `print` da página apos `CSS/JS` serem aplicados e executados?

Comment: Depende do momento da execução, se você aplicar o CSS por JavaScript e depois executar o html2canvas, sim irá funcionar. Porém se você está falando de elementos estáticos é necessário o `window.onload` para pode liberar o `html2canvas`. @RicardoHenrique **Nota:** Leia a parte da resposta que está escrito *Conclusão sobre tirar foto da página*.

Comment: GuilhermeNasicimento eu li esta parte, você entendeu mal minha pergunnta não quis dizer o CSS aplicado por javascript, eu quis dizer o css aplicado aos elementos html e a execução dos scripts javascripts (para renderizar imagens que estão em base64 e/ou fazer requisições AJAX para busca-las)

Comment: Se eu entendi, sim @RicardoHenrique o html2canvas tenta renderizar no estado atual, independente se o DOM foi manipulado manualmente ou por javascript.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento Ok entendi.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [*html2canvas*](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) que se adequa exatamente ao que você quer, pois ela "tira print" de qualquer divisão de uma página html.

[Aqui você encontra os exemplos de utilização](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html), mas deixarei um trecho de código abaixo para exemplificar:

```js
$("#PrintTrigger").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    html2canvas($("#Print"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#Print {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="Print">
    <h1>Vai printar esta div e repetí-la abaixo:</h1>
</div>
<button id="PrintTrigger">Tirar Print</button>
```

### Funcionamento

O código JS é bem simples:

```
html2canvas(elemento, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    // Ação à realizar, ao renderizar a imagem (print)
  }
});
```

***elemento*** - Corresponde à divisão da página html à qual você quer "printar" (Podendo sem um Elemento DOM, um ID ou uma Classe) 
***onrendered*** - Função que será executada assim que o "print" for renderizado. Nesta função você pode utilizar AJAX para enviar ao servidor sem recarregar a página, enfim, as possibilidades são inúmeras.

Answer (score 3):

Eu já faço uso do *Headless Browser* **PhantomJS** para download de páginas WEB Completas renderizadas de forma FIEL a exibida no browser comum (ele interpreta o JS e CSS) mas com ele tambem é possivel realizar um *print screen* da página desejada da sequinte forma:

- Crie um arquivo com extensão .js
- Cole e salve o seguinte conteúdo:

Comando que acessa uma determinada página e salva o conteúdo da mesma em um .png (mas pode salvar como PDF):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {
  page.render('stackoverflow.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

- chame-o da seguinte foma na linha de comandos: nome do programa (caso ele tenha sido inserido no path) mais npath do arquivo javascript criado no item acima ficando da seguinte forma:

  phantomjs teste.js

Com ele tambem é possivel estabelecer as dimensões da janela onde o site é exibido (isto é util caso queira ver como está sendo renderizado um site responsivo) da seguinte forma (esta configuração deve ser feita antes do page.open()):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

Você pode chama-lo usando o comando shell_exec desta forma:

```
    $pathToPhantomJS = 'C:\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs';
    $pathToJSScript = 'GetPage.js';
    $comand = $pathToPhantomJS . ' ' . $pathToJSScript . ' ' . $site;
    shell_exec($comand);
```

Obs: passo uma terceira variavel que representa o site a ter sua pagina *printada* o site é pego pelo vetor de args que são passados para o shell.

É possivel criar um CRON JOB para executar o comando `phantomjs teste.js` em determinado horário.

O PhantomJS me foi muito util e é muito configuravel e não conseguiria descrever todas a possibilidades aqui então estou colando alguns links Oficial e não Oficias que poderão ser uteis:

> Obs: Um ponto relevante levantado pelo usuário @GuilhermeNascimento é que esta solução só funciona do lado `Servidor` ou em seu `Desktop`.

**Download**

Link: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

**Documentação**

Screen Capture: [Link](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

viewportSize: [Link](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)

shell_exec (PHP): [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: Acabei de ler sobre o assunto, único problema é que está lib usa a engine WebKit portanto não irá renderizar da mesma maneira que é visualizado a página pelo usuário, mas para criar um sistema de portfólios, galerias, etc. realmente é uma incrível solução. Uma nota legal é deixar algo como "isto só funciona no lado do servidor"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento olha já realizei vários prints e sempre vieram de forma semelhante a exibida no chrome/firefox é provável (e já aconteceu comigo) é que alguns sites identificam que ele não possui certos complementos como o flash player e não retornam o conteúdo que deveria ser retornado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento alguns servidores identificam que não se trata de um navegador como firefox /ie/chrome e não enviam o HTML completo (somente o head), enviam um código javascript anti-robot ou deixa em loop infinito.

Comment: Entendo, apesar de renderizar bem semelhantes, os motores (Gecko, Webkit e Blink (*fork do webkit*)) ainda sim podem ter diferenças, principalmente se o desenvolvedor da página que será "fotografada" tiver feito algo que conflita com o motor de renderização, mas fora estes eventuais problemas, a dica é muito boa e estou pensando seriamente em usar no meu servidor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Use, gosto bastante e tem MUITAS outras funcionalidades se não fosse os empecilhos destacados no comentário acima seria quase perfeito. para o objetivo de printar a uma outra pergunta onde tambem dei esta mesma resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/714/como-exportar-uma-p%C3%A1gina-html-php-para-pdf/60104#60104

Comment: +1 lá também, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Com PHP creio que não dá para ser feito, mas com Javascript e `canvas` (HTML5) sim.

Com o advento do HTML5, novas tags foram implementadas, um deles é o `canvas`, que possibilita realizar essa tarefa.

Com o elemento `canvas` você pode criar gráficos, composições de fotos, animações, imagens 2D, 3D e existem várias APIs que te fornecem inúmeros recursos, como a [**html2canvas**](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), e é esta API que vamos trabalhar.

Primeiramente vamos entrar no site e baixar o arquivo. Imagino que você já tenha baixado o arquivo `jquery.js`.

O **html2canvas** tem um método inicial chamado `Preload`, que recebe dois parâmetros.

- **Element**: É o elemento que você deseja estar renderizando, por default é document.body
- **Options**: São as opções de renderização.
- **Complete**: função callback que será chamada depois do Preloading
- **Logging**: Loga os eventos no console
- **Proxy**: Url da página que vai ser usada como proxy
- **Timeout**: Tempo para carregamento das imagens

O *script* executa o seguinte comportamento:

1. Executar o Preload da página
2. Executar o Parse dos Elementos
3. Executar o Render do Objeto

Vamos ao código:

```
<script>
    $(window).ready(function () {
        html2canvas.Preload(document.body, {
            complete: function (images) {
                var queue = html2canvas.Parse();
                var canvas = html2canvas.Renderer(queue, { elements: { length: 1} });
                var img = canvas.toDataURL();
                openConsole("<img src='" + img + "'><p>");
            }
        });
        function openConsole(content) {
            top.console = window.open('', 'myconsole',
              'width=350,height=250'
               + ',menubar=0'
               + ',toolbar=1'
               + ',status=0'
               + ',scrollbars=1'
               + ',resizable=1')
            top.console.document.writeln(
              '<html><head><title>Console</title></head>'
               + '<body bgcolor=white onLoad="self.focus()">'
               + content
               + '</body></html>'
             )
            top.console.document.close()
        };
    });
</script>
```

Lembrando que os browsers que aceitam `canvas` são Chrome, FF, Opera e IE7+

Para mais informações, dê uma olhada neste artigo:

http://imasters.com.br/artigo/24443/javascript/screenshot-com-canvas-e-javascript/

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Comment: @williamhk2 valeu a dica, coloquei o código na minha resposta.

Comment: A versão fornecida no exemplo já está em desuso faz tempo, eu acompanho e colaboro eventualmente com o projeto html2canvas, a versão atual é a 0.5.0-rc. No link fala que tem suporte para IE7, mas isto era quando havia o "html2canvas-flash-fallback", esta parte do projeto foi descontinuada. Links no SOpt: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57155/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55522/3635